# Scala - save creation time on overrided object creation

Tags: scala, implicit

I want to save the time when I instantiate my object.

With the following code, time changes each time I want to know the creationDate:

```
class MyClass()

class DatedClass(myClass: MyClass) {
  val creationDate: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
}

implicit def CachedWrapperClassifier(myClass: MyClass) = {
  new DatedClass(myClass)
}

val obj = new MyClass
println(obj.creationDate)  
Thread.sleep(1000)
println(obj.creationDate)
```

Both given dates are NOT equal ... any idea why!?

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE:**

First, thank you for your responses!

I want to choose the Trait solution but this does not work anymore, if I want to use a separated method to retrieve the object ...

```
trait CreationTime {
  val creationTime: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
}

class MyClass()

def getMyClass: MyClass = {
  new MyClass with CreationTime
}

val obj = getMyClass
println(obj.creationTime) // creationTime is not accessible
Thread.sleep(1000)
println(obj.creationTime)
```

But I can NOT touch "MyClass".

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: scala is a statically typed language, if you get rid of the type, one way to get it back is by casting. 
   println(obj.asInstanceOf[CreationTime].creationTime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your compiler will replace your calls to `creationDate` with the implicit conversion. To call the method, the compiler will create a new wrapper object for each call to `creationDate`. What the compiler does has the same effect as doing the following:

```scala
val obj = new MyClass
println(new DatedClass(obj).creationDate)  
Thread.sleep(1000)
println(new DatedClass(obj).creationDate)
```

Since the constructor is called twice, the creation dates are different.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response!
So I see ... mmmh ... any idea how I can avoid this?
I want to override MyClass but I don´t want to have a new instance each time! :/

Comment: I don't know of any way to circumvent this. I think you can't keep track of the creation time without altering `MyClass` or the call to the constructor. A trait as Jesper suggested is one way of doing it, but there is no implicit way.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this differently is by using a trait as a mixin:

```
trait CreationDate {
  val creationDate: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
}

val obj = new MyClass with CreationDate
println(obj.creationDate)  
Thread.sleep(1000)
println(obj.creationDate)
```

Comment: Nice and simple! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you probably want to use a trait, which will simplify your code:

```
trait CreateTime {
    val createTime: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
}
```

You can attach it to your class either by extending it in the class definition:

```
class MyClass() extends CreateTime
```

Or when you create your object:

```
val obj = new MyClass with CreateTime
```

Also, pay attention to your variable names. What you called `creationDate` really is not a date... it's a time (or a timestamp). It's important to be clear with your variable names.

Comment: Yes, thx for the tipp regarding variable names. You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

`obj` is an implicit conversion wrapper, so you are getting a new instance each time you use it.

if you add a println you will see what is happening

```
class DatedClass(myClass: MyClass) {
  println("new instance")
  val creationDate: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
}
```